# Problems with www prefix in flask after setting SERVER_NAME for subdomains

Tags: python, apache, flask, subdomain

After I set the variable SERVER_NAME to be able to use subdomains with blueprints, all pages that before worked with www. as well does not work anymore. 
I set

```
SERVER_NAME = mydomain.com
```

my apache sites-available conf files looks like this

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName mydomain.com
            ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
            ServerAdmin email@mydomain.com
            WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
            <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            LogLevel warn
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined </VirtualHost> 


   < VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName subdomain.mydomain.com
            ServerAdmin email@mydomain.com
            WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
            <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            LogLevel warn
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined </VirtualHost>
```

Is there a proper way of fixing this, or is the only way some redirects?

Answer (score 0):

Have to added A record for www.
If not please add the same:
goto : DNS -> SELECT DOMAIN -> ADD RECORD -> Select record type "A" 
hostname : www
IP Adress : {Your Public IP}

Comment: The A records are set, both with and without www. You mean the access log or the error log? Because none of them seem to contain much